# How do I copy directories and symlink files?

Tags: symlink, cp

I have got a directory of huge files (total ~ 1TB) and I don't want copy them around. However, I'd like to work around them, so it would be convenient to have them linked in a directory hierarchy I have access to (aka one I created). So

```
/path/to/dirs/
  foo
  bar
  baz/
    tri
```

Should be copied to

```
~/path/to/dirs/
  foo -> /path/to/dirs/foo
  bar -> /path/to/dirs/bar
  baz/
    tri -> /path/to/dirs/tri
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. What is the problem, the number of directories? Finding the lowest-level directories by script? Do `foo` and `bar` not have subdirectories?

Comment: I put slashes where there should be. The question is how to copy directories and symlink files instead of copy both.

Comment: You want help. Obviously the people who shall help you decide "where slashes should be". Don't try to be more clever than those who shall get done what you can't. That `foo` is to be a file just because there is no slash is a strange assumption considering that its parent path is `path/to/dirs/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU:

```
cd ~/path/to/dirs || exit 1
find /path/to/dirs -type d -printf %P\\0 | xargs -0 mkdir -p 
find /path/to/dirs -type f -print0 | 
  xargs -0 cp --symbolic-link --parents --target-directory=.
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU coreutils (i.e. on non-embedded Linux or Cygwin):

```
cp -al /path/to/dirs ~/path/to/dirs
```

If your `cp` doesn't have the `-l` option, make a first pass to create the directory hierarchy, then a second pass for the symbolic links:

```
find /path/to/dirs -type d -exec sh -c 'for x do mkdir "$HOME$x"; done' _ {} +
find /path/to/dirs ! -type d -exec sh -c 'for x do ln -s "$x" "$HOME$x"; done' _ {} +
```

You can combine the two passes into a single command if you prefer:

```
find /path/to/dirs -exec sh -c '
  for x do
    if [ -d "$x" ]; then
      mkdir "$HOME$x"
    else
      ln -s "$x" "$HOME$x"
    fi
  done
' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cp --no-dereference orig dest
```

This will preserve symlinks when copying. Here is the documentation:

```
 -P, --no-dereference         never follow symbolic links in SOURCE
 -p                           same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
```